# Replace selection inputs with clickable images

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

MY code below lets me take an HTML selection and provide a more user friendly image clickable version.  When an image is clicked, it selects the proper value in a hidden selection filed in the DOM.

I just need help in adjusting my code below to work on a selection that is on the page multiple times.

If it is on the page 10 times, I need to run this code 10 times.

I am not sure how to target each one separately though

**Preview**

HTML Selection gets turned into clickable Images like this below. The JavaScript reads the HTML Selection filed already on the page and clones it and replaces each value with images.  It then hides the original selection field.  When an image is clicked on, and appears selected, it is using JavaScript to select that value in the real hidden selector as well!...

[image]

**Live Demo**
http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/ov1a4apc/

**JavaScript**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    if ($('#page_template').length) {
        //$('#page_template').hide().after('<div id="page_template_visual"></div>');
        $('#page_template').after('<div id="page_template_visual"></div>');

        $('#page_template option').each(function() {
            var classname = $(this).val().replace('.php', '');
            if ($(this).is("[selected]")) {
                classname = classname + ' selected';
            }
            $('#page_template_visual').append('<a href="' + $(this).val() + '" class="' + classname + '"><small></small>' + $(this).text() + '</a>');
        });

        if (!$('#page_template option[selected]').length) {
            $('#page_template_visual a:first-child').addClass('selected');
        }

        $('#page_template_visual a').on('click', function() {
            $('#page_template_visual a').removeClass('selected');
            theValue = $(this).addClass('selected').attr('href');
            $("#page_template").val(theValue).attr('selected', true);
            return false;
        });

    }

});
```

**HTML Select**

```
<select name="page_template" id="page_template" selected="selected">
    <option value="default">Default Template</option>
    <option value="custom-archives.php">Archives Template</option>
    <option value="wpi/pdf_quote_bold.php">Bold</option>
    <option value="SOONcontact.php">Contact</option>
    <option value="page-invoice.php">Invoice</option>
    <option value="wpi/pdf_quote_modern.php">Modern</option>
    <option value="wpi/pdf_quote.php">Traditional</option>
</select>
```

**CSS**

```
#page_template{
    /* display: none; */
}

#page_template_visual {
        margin: 0 -10px;
}

#page_template_visual a {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 129px;
        height: 100px;
        margin: 0 5px 5px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #333333;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: none;
        background: url('http://i.imgur.com/7S9yzTY.png') no-repeat left top;
}

#page_template_visual a small {
        height: 64px;
        width: 119px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

/* You can define images for the options here based on the classnames */
#page_template_visual a.template-both-sidebar-page {background-position: right -100px;}
#page_template_visual a.template-left-sidebar-page {background-position: right top;}
#page_template_visual a.template-right-sidebar-page {background-position: left -100px;}

#page_template_visual a.selected {
        color: #559a08;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff;  
}

#page_template_visual a.selected small {
        background: rgba(106,189,15,0.1) url('http://i.imgur.com/P0E1jmh.png') no-repeat center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to change the `page_template` and `page_template_visual` ids to classes (in the HTML, JavaScript & CSS).

Then loop through all the elements with the `page_template` class, like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.page_template').each(function() {
        var $select = $(this);

        // Keep a reference to this element so you can use it below.
        var $visual = $('<div class="page_template_visual"></div>');

        $select.after($visual);

        $select.find('option').each(function() {
            var $option = $(this);
            var classname = $option.val().replace('.php', '');
            if ($option.is("[selected]")) {
                classname = classname + ' selected';
            }
            $visual.append('<a href="' + $option.val() + '" class="' + classname + '"><small></small>' + $option.text() + '</a>');
        });

        if (!$select.find('option[selected]').length) {
            $visual.find('a:first-child').addClass('selected');
        }

        // The next line could have been:
        //     $visual.find('a').on('click', function() {
        // But instead it uses event delegation, so only one
        // event handler is registered, instead of one for each <a>.
        $visual.on('click', 'a', function() {
            $visual.find('a').removeClass('selected');
            var value = $(this).addClass('selected').attr('href');
            $select.val(value);
            return false; // You don't need this, unless you really don't want the click event to bubble up.
        });
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kz1tyq56/)

Comment: awesome thanks.  My own attempt failed as my click event was targeting all of them!  This is perfect